# Elasticsearch- querying data that exceeds 10k

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

I've recently written an application that makes queries to Elasticsearch. I've always used the "from" and "size" fields to take care of pagination. I realized today that this doesn't work for datasets greater than 10,000.

I've looked into both scroll and search_after, and although both make sense I'm not sure which I could use for my application. Here are my requirements

1. I want to show 1000 results per page
2. I want to be able to click **NEXT** and see the next 1000 results
3. I want to click **BACK** and see the previous 1000 results, which I don't think scrolling allows me to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, `search_after` looks like a possible solution for your use case although you need to do what is suggested [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/29449#issuecomment-380216534) to achieve **BACK** pagination

Comment: Thanks for the link and it seems this is the better options. Unfortunately, my application allows users to sort on many fields, some of which are valued at "null" or empty is some sets. This may in fact end up getting very messy for my queries. Instead I might have to make a design change to stop showing data after 10,000 and asking the user to make a more specific query. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be to increase **max_result_window** property of the index. This will allow you to fetch more data using **from** and **size**.

Beware that it will increase the heap memory usage and time taken to fetch the results as  the size of the result depends on the **from+size**. It first fetches the **from+size**  results and stores it in memory then returns **from** amount of data. So, more **from+size**, more heap memory usage and more time take to fetch the results.

In the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html) it says:

> index.max_result_window
>   The maximum value of from + size for searches to this index. Defaults to 10000. Search requests take heap memory and time proportional to from + size and this limits that memory.

Comment: This unfortunately won't help since I'll return over 50k results sometimes. Thanks for the help regardless :)